# Place values inside bars of chart (Reporting Services 2008)

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I have a report with a chart containing some bars. They represent values from an underlying query. Now, I would like to place some more values, which are closely related to the first values, inside the bars like this:

[image]

Can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can achieve a similar effect:

- Add a dummy column (value 0) to your query.
- Change your chart type from a plain column to a stacked column.
- Add your dummy column to your chart.
- Right-click on the data label for your original value and select Series Label Properties.
  From the Series Label Properties dialog, in the General tab change the Label Data to be the new value that you want to appear inside the bar.
- With the data label for your original value still selected:

  - Check that the UseValueAsLabel property in the Properties Window is now set to False (you may have been prompted on whether to change this in the previous step.)
  - Change the Position property in the Properties Window to Auto - the label should now appear inside the bar.
- Right-click on the bar for your new, dummy value and enable Show Data Labels (if this is not already selected.)
- Right-click on the data label for your new, dummy value and select Series Label Properties. From the Series Label Properties dialog, in the General tab change the Label Data to be the original value that you want to appear above the original bar.
- With the data label for your new, dummy value still selected, check that the UseValueAsLabel property in the Properties Window is now set to False (you may have been prompted on whether to change this in the previous step.)

If you now preview the report, your new value should appear inside the bars and the existing value should appear on top of them.